# GRASS GIS 7 in QGIS 2.6.1, Windows 7 64bit - Missing dependency

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am using QGIS Brighton 2.6.1. Today I have installed Grass GIS 7.0.0 RC2 to try its topology functions in QGIS.

[image: Processing options]

I have activated the provider, set the paths, but everytime I try to use any Grass GIS 7 command, I get the "Missing dependency.This algorithm cannot be run :-(" error. Grass in standalone is working just fine. Windows 7 64bit user as it stands in the title.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated "Processing" to be compliant with GRASS GIS 7.0.x. Unless it is not backported to QGIS 2.6 (which would be easy), let's hope that it goes into the upcoming QGIS 2.8 release. The QGIS developers will know more.

Comment: Any update on the issue? I just installed the latest QGIS2.7 weekly and get the same error trying to use the Grass 7 Commands with Grass 7.0.0RC2 installed and configured.

Comment: You need to ask the QGIS developers... meanwhile you can download our test "grass7" package from here: http://aiolos.survey.ntua.gr/gisvm/dev/grass7.tar.gz (temporary link, used for OSGeo-Live 8.5) and unpack it alongside to the existing "grass" support in the processing directory. However, an official release is of course better.

Comment: Updated to 2.8.1, still having the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: Please consider to open a bug report with QGIS...